# Does NoClassDefFoundError have always ClassNotFoundException in caused by?

Tags: java, classloader, stack-trace, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

Can I assume that every `NoClassDefFoundError` thrown from JDK class loading mechanism will always have `ClassNotFoundException` as a cause in stacktrace?

Also, where actually `NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown and its cause is initialized to be `ClassNotFoundException`? I cannot find Java code responsible for that logic.

This is how usually stacktraces look to me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: package/Missing
    at package.Missing(Missing.java:110)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: package.Missing
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: why I get downvotes? what's wrong with my question?

Comment: You might find more info here http://www.baeldung.com/java-classnotfoundexception-and-noclassdeffounderror

Comment: @OlegSklyar where in this article is answer to my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I assume that every NoClassDefFoundError thrown from JDK class
>   loading mechanism will always have ClassNotFoundException as a cause
>   in stacktrace?

That's a reasonable assumption. According to the [Java Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3):

> If the Java Virtual Machine ever attempts to load a class C during
>   verification (§5.4.1) or resolution (§5.4.3) (but not initialization
>   (§5.5)), and the class loader that is used to initiate loading of C
>   throws an instance of ClassNotFoundException, then the Java Virtual
>   Machine must throw an instance of NoClassDefFoundError whose cause is
>   the instance of ClassNotFoundException.

I believe the above answers your second question as well.